# php/mysql : How to insert a gzcompress-ed string into a text mysql field?

Tags: php, mysql, text, compression, gzip

I have been trying to compress and store a json encoded string into mysql, but I am getting "unexpected /" errors.

I also tried to use addslashes like this:

```
addslashes(gzcompress(json_encode($mystring)));
```

And to display

```
json_decode(gzuncompress(stripslashes($mystring)));
```

But it fails on insert with the error I mentioned.

I read somewhere a string with gzcompress should be stored as a blob, but I was hoping there is a way to store it in a mysql text field so I dont have to mess with the db.

PS: Some asked for full error message here it is:

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string
>   value: '\x9C\xED}\x8Br\xDB...' for column 'field_text_value' at
>   row 1.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string should be used instead of addslashes (not saying that will fix this problem; I mean in general).  addslashes is not aware of character sets, whereas mysql_real_escape_string is actually aware of the database connection and can more accurately escape data.  addslashes() is one of the many things PHP did trying to help coders that should have never been done.

Comment: Thanks Corbin, will check that out as well. By the way whoever minus oned this please give an explanation why.

Comment: Storing "big arrays" in a *relational* database makes very little sense.
Asking questions providing them with not a full error message but rather with a stub says '"unexpected /"' makes even less sense. It is even impossible to tell, what part of the code issues this *stub*

Comment: @Corbin mysql_real_escape_string is not aware as well, unless you explicitly tell it otherwise. thus, just a recommendation "use it, not addslashes" will actually make no change at all.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  "Escapes special characters in the unescaped_string, taking into account the current character set of the connection so that it is safe to place it in a mysql_query()."  And as for the optional connection parameter: " If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed."

Comment: @Corbin mysql_real_escape_string knows nothing of the current character set. it has to be set explicitly set using mysql_set_charset() function. Othervise the default `latin1` would be used and mysql_real_escape_string will act exactly the same way as mysql_escape_string/addslashes. Anyway, all this stuff become insignificant as it turned out that our poor OP is using PDO, if which fact he told us nothing

Comment: @Col Shrapnel : I guess there is a reason php has serialize, or json encode and I am not the only one who needs this.  If I dont want to query the array in db just store it there is nothing wrong with the relational model.

Comment: Oh. I love such a speeches. "I guess there is a reason a man invented skis. There is nothing wrong in swimming using skis then." Go on.

Comment: Wont go on as we are getting off topic. Thanks for your help...

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel As long as it escapes according to the client charset, it should be secure.  If it doesn't match the table, the data may be stored wrong, but it will still be inserted securely.  Or are you referring to if someone uses a SET NAMES query and does not use mysql_set_charset?  Because yes, in that case, it is basically useless (if mysql_real_escape_string is unaware of the charset change). I plan on looking into the PHP and MySQL C lib code later, because as far as I know, mysql_real_escape_string is always aware of the connection charset.

Comment: you should be using addslashes on the UNCOMPRESSED data

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Store it as a `BLOB`. Even if there were a way to store it in a `VARCHAR` or `*TEXT` field in a way that survives a round trip, it would be a horrible way.

Are you sure you need compression anyway?

You can also make MYSQL do the compression, e.g. `INSERT INTO mytable (compressed_json) VALUE (COMPRESS('[\"the json\"]')`.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure, but gzcompress looked like a nice way to compress a string. Will investigate the blob way.

Comment: gzcompress produces binary data. `BLOB` column data type stores binary data. If you're not using gzcompress there's no point using `BLOB`. (All "blob" says is "mysql, do not try to rewrite these bits. This is not text, it has no encoding". How you put your bits in, whether with gzcompress or `COMPRESS()`, is up to you.)

Comment: Thanks it works with BLOB. Much appreciated. It takes up much less space with gzcompress.

Comment: Final numbers are out, managed to compress a table with 30 000 records, 1.7 GB, big json encoded arrays to 300 MB :D WOW Awesome. Added a new blob field, imported text field and gzcompressed it. Then deleted the old field.

Answer (score -2):

Why would you want to add a gzip compressed string into a database? Why don't you just store it as:

`mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($myArray)))`

Comment: It's a big array, I was hoping compression would make the arrays json encoded string even smaller.