# Efficient way to store html element in sql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm saving contents of a particular div in mysql database as html elements.
So the html elements  content includes many elements such as:

```
<div id="div0" class="box" style="z-index: 2; width: 1689px; height: 1013px;">
   <img style="margin: 0px; position: relative; display: block; height: 550px; width: 638px; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
</div>
```

Is there any way to reduce the data for efficiently storing in mysql database.

Such as any php or javascript functions to compress before saving to db.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're looking to compress it?  Are you having storage or performance issues?

Comment: @Fosco: maybe he's storing *really* large fragments and they don't fit :-)

Comment: You could always `base64_encode()` the string to compress it slightly.  It may not make much of a difference though in length.

Comment: @Tim I don't think `base64_encode` will help much on this ;)

Comment: @Fosco: The field is too large and I think its not best practice to store too large data in single field. I'm storing a html prototype inside a div (the application is a wire frame builder )

Comment: @user1156468 Too large in your opinion, or too large that it fails to insert?  Best Practice is a nonsense term.

Comment: @Fosco: too large is my opinion. The example given above is the minute extract from the actual content.

Comment: Too large for what? Compression is a very broad topic and the correct answer greatly depends on the situation. As others have mentioned, you need greatly detail the purpose: should it be searchable? If it needs to be searchable, is there some reason you can't generate keywords and use those for the search? Is it retrieved frequently or rarely? Is there some reason you can't use a text field? It sounds like you're trying to fit a square peg in a round hole :)

Comment: @user1156468 Then it is not actually too large.  Consider that many people are storing massive XML documents in databases now.  Go with it, and don't waste CPU cycles on compression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could compress the string before saving it to the database using `gzcompress()`/`gzuncompress()` PHP functions or you can do it with mysql using `COMPRESS()`/`UNCOMPRESS()` in your queries - but unless you have very much data I would not recommend this.

You win some harddisk space, but you lose a lot of transparency (search, edit, convert, migrate...)

Comment: I used gzcompress along with the BLOB datatype for db fields,
[Details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516161/php-mysql-how-to-insert-a-gzcompress-ed-string-into-a-text-mysql-field)

Answer (score 5):

Why compress? Disk space is cheap, and storing it in a compressed (e.g. gzip) format will just cost you CPU time to decompress/recompress each time.

As well, once you compress the data, it becomes an opaque binary blob to the DB, and you lose any ability to search that text via substring/fulltext.